# Convert a mm-yy string "Jan-01" into date format

Tags: r, date

The date in my original Excel file represents the monthly data in the format of "Jan-01". Of course, I can manually convert them to something more useful in the Excel first and then input that into R.

How can I convert such adate into a Date class in R?

Comment: As mentioned clearly in the title, it's month and year, not month and date. strptime("Jan-01","%b-%d") [1] "2012-01-01" > strptime("Jan-01","%b-%y") [1] NA

Comment: Add a 1 to the front to represent the first day of the month: `datevar <- "Jan-01"; as.Date(paste("01",datevar,sep="-"),"%d-%b-%y");`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want a `date` class, use as.Date:

```
x <- "Jan-01"
as.Date(paste("01-", x, sep = ""), format = "%d-%b-%y")
```

If you want a `POSIXct` class, consider using `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- "Jan-01"
dmy(paste("01-", x , sep =""))
```

If you want to just rely on `base`:

```
x <- "Jan-01"
as.POSIXct(paste("01-", x, sep = ""), format = "%d-%b-%y")
```

Comment: As the OP noted, your first `as.Date` gives an `NA` result as R can't guess the full date.

Comment: `lubridate` conveniently has a `my` function, `dmy` and `paste` therefore isn't necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Edit:

The easiest way is to use the yearmon class in zoo:

```
 require(zoo)
 as.yearmon(x, "%b-%y")
#[1] "Jan 2001"
```

Somewhat longer method:

```
 x="Jan-01"
 xs<-strsplit(x, "-")
 xd <- as.Date( xs[[1]][2], paste( xs[[1]][1], "01",  sep="-"), format="%y-%b-%d")
 xd
#[1] "2001-01-01"
```

If you want to process a string of dates, then you may need to use `sapply` if picking the second method to make a vector of years and a vector of months

Comment: Please refer to the title, it's month and year, not month and date.                                                              > xd <- as.Date(paste(xs[[1]][1], xs[[1]][2], sep="-"), format="%b-%y") 
> xd
[1] NA
> xd <- as.Date(paste(xs[[1]][1], xs[[1]][2], sep="-"), format="%b-%Y") 
> xd
[1] NA
> xd <- as.Date(paste(xs[[1]][1], xs[[1]][2], sep="-"), format="d%-%b-%Y") 
> xd
[1] NA

Comment: OK, easy to fix. The format spec for two digit year is %y rather than %Y

Answer (score 0):

If you forcibly specify the first day of the month you can convert the dates as so:

```
datevar <- c("Jan-01","Feb-01","Mar-12")
as.Date(paste("01",datevar,sep="-"),"%d-%b-%y")
```

It should be noted that this is essentially the same answer as DWin has below, just manually specifying the day instead of the year.